# Does lifetime of a const auto reference inside a ranged-based for loop extends to the end of the scope?

Tags: c++

I have ran across a bit of code, that clears a deque while inside a range-based for loop. The const auto reference is still used subsequently. Here is a small reproduction.

```
struct Foo
{
    int x;
}

deque<Foo> q1;
deque<Foo> q2;
q1.push_front({0});
q1.push_front({1});

for (const auto& ref : q1)
{
    if (ref.x == 1)
    {
        q1.clear();
        q2.push_front(ref);
        break;
    }
}
std::cout << q2.front().x << std::endl;
```

This q2 appears to have gotten the value of ref. But I am thinking that the `q1.clear()` should have deleted the underlying data of `ref`.

1. Does the lifetime for the reference last through the scope, or is this an undefined behaviour?
2. If it is an undefined behaviour, why is this working???

edit: missed the break from the original code, added back to narrow down the discussion.

Comment: undefined behavior doesn't mean the code wont work "correctly".  Valid output is part of the set of all possible outcomes.  This is why UB is so dangerous.  The code could work on one machine, but not another.

Comment: The contents of the `if` are not executed. `q1.front().x` is 0.

Comment: A reference doesn't have a lifetime, the object it refers to does. When that object's lifetime ends, the reference becomes invalid. Lifetime extension by binding to a const reference only applies to temporary objects.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Does the lifetime for the reference last through the scope, or is this an undefined behaviour?

To start with, the following range-based for loop:

```
for (auto const& ref : q1) {
  // ...
}
```

expands, as per [[stmt.ranged]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/stmt.ranged#1), to

```
{
  auto &&range = (q1);
  for (auto begin_ = range.begin(), end_ = range.end(); begin_ != end_;
       ++begin_) {
    auto const& ref = *begin_;
    // ...
  }
}
```

Now, as per the docs for [`std::deque<T>::clear`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/clear):

> Erases all elements from the container. After this call, size() returns zero.
>
> **Invalidates any references, pointers, or iterators referring to contained elements.** Any past-the-end iterators are also invalidated.

if the `if (ref.x == 1)` branch is ever entered, then past the point of `q1.clear();` the iterator whose pointed-to object `ref` is referring to (here: the deque element) is invalidated, and any further use of the iterator is undefined behavior: e.g. incrementing it an dereferencing it in the next loop iteration.

Now, in this particular example, as the *for-range-declaration* is `auto const&` as compared to only `auto &`, *if* the `*begin_` dereferencing (prior to invalidating iterators) resolves to a value and not a reference, this (temporary) value would bind to the `ref` reference and have its lifetime extended. However, `std::deque` is a sequence container and shall adhere to the requirements of [[sequence.reqmts]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/sequence.reqmts), where particularly [Table 78](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/sequence.reqmts#tab:container.seq.opt) specifies:

> /3 In Tables 77 and 78, X denotes a sequence container class, a denotes a value of type X [...]
>
> Table 78:
>
> - Expression: `a.front()`
> - Return type: `reference;` (`const_­reference` for constant `a`)
> - Operational semantics: `*a.begin()`

Whilst not entirely water-proof, it seems highly likely that dereferencing a `std::deque` iterator (e.g. `begin()` or `end()`) yields a reference type, something both Clang and GCC agrees on:

```
#include <deque>
#include <type_traits>

struct S{};

int main() {
    std::deque<S> d;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(*d.begin()), S&>, "");
               // Accepted by both clang and gcc.   
}
```

in which case the use of `ref` in

> ```
>  q2.push_front(ref);
> ```

is UB after the `q1.clear()`.

We may also note that the `end()` iterator, stored as `end_`, is also invalidated by the invocation of `clear()`, which is another source of UB once the invariant of the expanded loop is tested in the next iteration.

---

> If it is an undefined behaviour, why is this working???

Trying to reason with undefined behavior is a futile exercise.

Comment: Probably a little bit offtopic for this question: Why is there a new variable `range` introduced instead of just using `q1`?

Comment: @mch `q1` here may represent an expression with side effects. So you only want to evaluate that expression once.

Comment: @mch - You can have an arbitrary expression for  the range. Even one that produces a temporary object. It needs to be extended.

Comment: `std::deque` iterator type is a [LegacyRandomAccessIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator) which is a [LegacyBidirectionalIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator) which is a [LegacyForwardIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ForwardIterator) which is a [LegacyIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Iterator) where the result of evaluating `*it` is _"unspecified"_ - so it might return a temporary and then lifetime extension should apply (if it returns a reference then UB).

Comment: @RichardCritten Good point, it particularly applies here as the _for-range-declaration_ is `auto const&` and not just `auto&`: I expanded answer some with this discussion.

Comment: @RichardCritten - LegacyBidirectionalIterator specifies `*a--` as being `std::iterator_traits<It>::reference`. Which in this case *is* a proper reference. These named requirements are meant to "subsume" each other. Multi-pass guarantees mean we can further specify what `*it` does.

Comment: Afaict from https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/sequence.reqmts#3 the iterators of `deque` shall fulfill, additionally, the requirements of Cpp17InputIterator, which as per https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/input.iterators#tab:inputiterator specifies the return type or `*it` as a `reference`.

Comment: Wow, this is my first post, surprised to see so many comments so soon. Thanks for all your comments!

Still new and trying to understand half the things that are mentioned.
Edited in the break so to focus on the lifetime of ref.